# want them to be all (=want all of them to be): grammatical?

Tags: quantifiers

In the following two examples, the construction "want them to be all" is used to mean "want all of them to be":

> (1) Statistics show that children who read proficiently by the third grade realize better academic outcomes. Literacy experts view third grade as a time when a child transitions from learning to read to reading to learn. "We want them to be **all** great readers and be the best they can be in their community," [[Source](http://goo.gl/qJmLCY)]
>
> (2) I admit that I remain a little finicky when it comes to surprises. I want them to be **all** birthday presents or letters from old friends. [[Source](http://goo.gl/dMwJ6n)]

Is this construction grammatical and natural?
I'd like to know what native speakers think.

Comment: It sounds off to me; I would say "we want them all to be" instead. It is the kind of thing you might hear someone say occasionally, if they're building the sentence as they speak and the decision to emphasize with 'all' comes after the point where it should naturally have been inserted.  In written text, however, it certainly looks like a plain old mistake.

Comment: This is called *quantifier float(ing)*: *all*, *both* and *each* qualifying the subject may move to other points in a sentence. There's a description of the rules [here](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/Quantifier-Floating.htm)

Answer (score 1):

This construction does not sound natural to me. If I correctly understand [the document that StoneyB referred to](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/Quantifier-Floating.htm), it is not grammatically correct either.

> ...it cannot move over the infinitive, as shown in (31g).
>   
>      (31)
>      ...
>      g. *I want my friends to be **all** at the airport

Note that there is also an adverbal use of [all](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/all), meaning **completely**. The rules for adverb placement are different, and it can occur after the **to be** infinitive, or indeed after any other verb. These examples demonstrate the difference:

> They **all** seem to be upset - *quantifier for **they** - all of them are upset* 
>   They seem to be **all** upset - *adverb qualifying **upset** - they are completely upset*

Answer (score 0):

The constructions are not *grammatical*, as the link provided by StoneyB points out. In both of them, the quantifier **all** *floats over* (or moves past) the infinitive **to be**.

However, "We want them to be all great readers" would be clearly understood by most readers, and is somewhat *natural* in American English, perhaps cognate with the idiomatic use of the quantifier **all** as an adverb in the compound phrase **all like** in colloquial speech, e.g.:

> So I'm **all like** "he said whaaaa?"

There may be a hint of this idiomatic usage in the sentence "We want them to be **all** great readers and be the best they can be in their community." It's important to recognize that this source is quoted speech, while your second source is casual or "chatty" writing. In formal writing, and for clarity, you should strive to observe the *quantifier float* rules in the provided link.

Comment: The verbs in your two example sentences are not infinitives: they are present simple (**am**) and past simple (**was**). The rule only applies to the infinitive  (**to be**). Compare these two sentences: "they are **all** teachers" - **OK** and "they want to be **all** teachers" - **not OK**.

Comment: @JavaLatte Obviously, but my objective was to demonstrate how the use of **all** can be idiomatic, and how the usage in the OP's examples may be cognate with that idiom.

Comment: The usages that you quoted are adverbal usages of **all**, meaning **completely**.  The rules for placement of adverbs are different from those of quantifiers, and could legitimately be used after a **to be** infinitive, for example "He seemed to be all confused". See the adverb section of this definition: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/all

Comment: Again: obviously. Again: I was not proposing some sort of equivalency between the contructions and usages. I was suggesting that the idiomatic usages of **all** may have influenced the author of _We want them to be all great readers_ in forming that sentence; thus "cognate with."